# Use the definition of limit to prove that $\lim_{z\to z_0} (az + b) = az_0 + b$, a,b belongs to complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification, complex-numbers

Here what i already done:

\begin{align*} |az+b-(az_0+b)&+|az-az_0+b-b|\\&=|a(z-z_0)|\\&=|a||z-z_0|{\le}|a|*{\Delta}|z-z_0|
\end{align*}

If ${\Delta}=1$ and we know that $0{\lt}|z-z_0|{\lt}1$, then:

$||z|-|z_0||{\le}|z-z_0|<1 \\{\to} |z|{\lt}1+|z_o|$

Then:

$|z|<1+|z_0| {\to} |z+z_0|{\le}|z|+|z_0|{\le}1+2|z_0|$

So:

${\Delta}|a|*(1+2|z_0|)\\ = {\Delta}(|a|*(1+2|z_0|)={\epsilon}\\ {\to} {\Delta} = {\epsilon}/(|a|(|1+2|z_0|)$

Then:

$|az+b - (az_0 + b)| {\lt} |a|{\Delta}|z-z_0|\\ {\le} {\Delta}(|a|(1+2|(z_0)|\\{\lt}{\epsilon}/(|a|(1+2|z_0|)*(|a|(1+2|z_0|) = {\epsilon}$

That proves:

$\lim_{z\to z_0} (az + b) = az_0 + b$

Is that correct?

Comment: For $a\neq 0$, from the first three lines of your reasoning you could just select: $$0<|z-z_0|<\delta=\epsilon/|a| \implies |az+b-(az_0+b)|<\epsilon$$
And then consider the case where $a=0$.

Comment: @projectilemotion You forget the case $a = 0$.

Comment: I didn't forget it, in that case you could just take any $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems okay in general (but your approach is more complex than it should), just some fixes.

First of all, you need to consider the case $a=0 \in \mathbb C$. Then, if that's the case, you have nothing to prove, as it's straightforward. Then you can go on by considering the case $a\neq 0 \in \mathbb C$.

**But** for a more fast and elegant approach, observe that

$$|az + b - (az_0 + b)| = |a||z-z_0| < \varepsilon \implies  |z-z_0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{|a|+1}$$

considering $a=0$ and $a\neq 0$ at the same time, thus you're finished.